# Access object property in class method

Tags: javascript, this

In many other questions it's explained why `this` in the Say method below isn't always referring to an object of Foo.

```
class Foo {
    constructor(){
        this.bar = "baz";
    }

    Say(){
        alert(this.bar);
    }
}
```

I want to make sure that `Say()` will result in the same alert regardless of how it's called.
I only control the code above, not the examples below.

```
var f = new Foo();
f.Say();                                    //"baz"
element.addEventListener("click", f.Say);   //undefined
f.Say.call({bar: "no"});                    //"no"
```

I have a roughly idea of how to build an implementation using functions.

```
function Foo(){
    var bar = "baz";
    return {
        Say(){
            alert(bar);
        }
    }
}
```

Can this be assured using the class syntax?

Comment: No, not with `class` syntax, but when you bind the event handler you could also bind the function to `f`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Foo {
    constructor(){
        this.bar = "baz";
        this.Say = this.Say.bind(this);
    }

    Say(){
        alert(this.bar);
    }
}
```

With this, you force that the context of the `Say` method will always be `this`.

You are actually adding a new property to each `Foo` instance with the same name as the property `Say` in its prototype, so this new property will take precedence over the prototype, and setting it as the same function but with the context forced with bind.

EDIT: You can automate it with something like this:

```js
class Foo {
    constructor(){
        this.bar = "baz";
        Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this.constructor.prototype).forEach((i) => {
            if (typeof this.constructor.prototype[i] == "function" && this.constructor.prototype[i] != this.constructor) {
                this[i] = this.constructor.prototype[i].bind(this);
            }
        });
    }

    Say(){
        alert(this.bar);
    }
}
var f = new Foo();
f.Say();
f.Say.call({bar: "no"});
```

Comment: Doesn't this make `Say()` completely redundant? Can't we just define `this.Say` as an arrow function and forget about `Say()`?

Comment: this seems legit bnut wouldn't that force you to always bind the class methods explicitly. i mean if you had many methods, this would mean you need to write many bind statements also

Comment: @MarkMeyer Yep. But when I do this, I prefer to keep it this way, as I like to have the class methods defined in the prototype, but only as a convention. Maybe in the futuro I don't need to bind, so I can directly remove that line and keep the method without too much work, or maybe there's a class helper somewhere that accesses the methods via the cosntructor prototype because of whatever reason... I don't know, I just like to feel "safe" when doing this xD

Comment: @FayçalArab You can create the helper I said. Edited the answer.

Comment: That sounds reasonable @JorgeFuentesGonzález

Comment: what if you use the classic `_self = this;` variable inside the class, then you use `_self` instead of `this`

Comment: @ Jorge Fuentes González sorry didn't notice. my bad.

Comment: @FayçalArab is it possible to access `_self` in the class? I thought I had to use `this` to access class variables.

Comment: You can access whatever variable you created in the function scope.

Comment: The automation doesn't work, it never stops at any methods.